# Linux Mint 18 Sarah KDE Update Manager

Tags: linux-mint, kde

I recently clean installed Mint 18 KDE on a MacBook Air, and the Update Manager in the system tray has no default behavior.  I would like it to open the Update Manager, but instead I have to right click it and choose Update Manager.  I've been trying to find the configuration for that item in the system tray so that I can enable a default behavior, but either I haven't found the correct config file, or I was unable to determine the correct setting.  Can anyone point me to the correct file and the correct setting?

Thanks in advance,
syserss

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to set the defaults for a KDE system tray entry?

Answer (score 0):

The same occurs for me on Linux Mint KDE 18.2
To access the update manager I point the cursor over the shield icon, then press the touchpad with two fingers and then I can point to a dialog box that says update manager and I finally could get the task. I suppose that the same can be done pressing both buttons of the mouse.
Regards: Héctor